# how to connect to an application from inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have created  a docker container which is running on a particular VM in azure (or consider any cloud).That container has a java/nodejs/Csharp application running which needs to access Jenkins server which is running in a company network.

So will i be able to access jenkins from that docker container?If no,please provide a solution on how to access.

Comment: Yes, if that Jenkins instance has a publicly reachable IP address. Otherwise it depends on the setup, maybe some VPN would have to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use --network=host option to let your container run in the same network context as the server you're trying to connect to if it's accessible from the container host.

Of course you should specify a specific network or routes if possible.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings

Comment: So,you are saying a docker container can access jenkins server that is outside the container but running on some OS machine in a network...Is that correct?

Comment: and if the host is diff,i mean container is running in docker installed in different VM and jenkins in diff VM,will this work?

Comment: I don't get what exactly is your problem: A container can access anything present in the network of the host usually without any hussle. You just need to ensure the thing you try to connect to is mapped in the network. Either by publishing its container ports to the host or using the net directive. Maybe you start trying it out?